# Can't get path to internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm using the [Android-Download-Manager-Pro](https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro) library from GitHub for downloading files on android.

After the download is finished, in the logs I see this:

```
Create file address: /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/uHlNhjA7c_g_27.jpg
```

It's a path to a file, which was downloaded a moment ago. When I try to create the File value and access it, I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/uHlNhjA7c_g_27.jpg");
```

When I look at the length of the file in logs, it's always 0. How do I correctly get access to the downloaded file?

Comment: Could you please link the lib?

Comment: @Mauker sorry, i typo in name of thi lib. Here is: https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, i forgot to add permissions to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html). Don't be confuse with the name of the function. Read this in the documentation:

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Comment: Result was the same. Finaly i have full path: /storage/emulated/0/Downloads/uHlNhjA7c_g_27.jpg in file value, i saw this in logs, but it have 0 size

Comment: Try different ways with this function (e.g. /Downloads/uHlNhjA7c_g_27.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

This adress could be the right one. Not sure for that:

```
 File saveFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) , "uHlNhjA7c_g_27.jpg");
```

Acording to docs:

> Standard directory in which to place files that have been downloaded by the user.

Comment: i tried this, and result was the same. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory returns just path, finaly path-string with my image the same..